# Emacs + Geiser on Windows - Hangs when running Chicken Scheme in the REPL

Tags: windows, emacs, read-eval-print-loop, chicken-scheme, geiser

After one or two rounds of expressions loaded from the buffer into the REPL with `C-c C-b` or `C-c M-b`, Emacs hangs until I press `C-g`.  Sometimes it ends up switching to the REPL, but even when it does the last sexp never gets evaluated.
I can't find a way to debug or find where it's hanging.

This happens on a fresh install with only a few packages.  Here is `init.el`:

```
;;-------------------------
;; MELPA
;;-------------------------
(require 'package)
(let* ((no-ssl (and (memq system-type '(windows-nt ms-dos))
                    (not (gnutls-available-p))))
       (proto (if no-ssl "http" "https")))
  ;; Comment/uncomment these two lines to enable/disable MELPA and MELPA Stable as desired
  (add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa" (concat proto "://melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  ;;(add-to-list 'package-archives (cons "melpa-stable" (concat proto "://stable.melpa.org/packages/")) t)
  (when (< emacs-major-version 24)
    ;; For important compatibility libraries like cl-lib
    (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . (concat proto "://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))))
(package-initialize)
;; LIST PACKAGES
(setq package-list '(helm
                     ;scheme-complete ;;suspect it messes with chicken & geiser
                     ;chicken-scheme ;;suspect it messes with chicken & geiser
                     paredit
                     geiser
                     slime
                     restart-emacs
                     use-package
                     flycheck
                     ;; sublimity
                     solarized-theme
                     zenburn-theme))
                     ; list the repositories containing them
(setq package-archives '(("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/")
                        ("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))

; activate all the packages (in particular autoloads)
(package-initialize)

; fetch the list of packages available
(unless package-archive-contents
 (package-refresh-contents))

; install the missing packages
(dolist (package package-list)
 (unless (package-installed-p package)
   (package-install package)))
;;-------------------------
;; THA LOOKS
;;-------------------------
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
(set-face-attribute 'default t :font "hack")
(set-frame-font "hack" nil t)
;; other fonts "IBM Plex Mono"
(tool-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
;(desktop-save-mode 1) ;;isn't working right with buffers and geiser
;;-------------------------
;; USE PACKAGE
;;-------------------------
(use-package flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init (global-flycheck-mode))
;;-------------------------
;; HELM
;;-------------------------
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x) ;; bind to M-x
(helm-mode 1) ;; common Emacs command completion
;;-------------------------
;; flycheck
;;-------------------------
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
;;-------------------------
;; SLIME
;;-------------------------
;; Set your lisp system and, optionally, some contribs
;;(setq inferior-lisp-program "/opt/sbcl/bin/sbcl") ;scbl isn't installed
(setq slime-contribs '(slime-fancy))
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy slime-banner))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages
   (quote
    (zenburn-theme solarized-theme flycheck use-package restart-emacs slime geiser paredit helm))))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Here is last buffer (in scheme-mode with chicken selected):

```
(define (test x) (+ x x))
(define (test2 y x) (* x y x y x y))
```

Here is the REPL:

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2017, The CHICKEN Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.13.0 (rev 68eeaaef)
windows-mingw32-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2017-12-11 on yves.more-magic.net (Linux)

; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/chicken-doc.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/chicken.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/matchable.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/lolevel.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/regex.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/irregex.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/srfi-13.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/posix.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/data-structures.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/srfi-69.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/extras.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/files.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/utils.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/srfi-1.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/csi.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/chicken-doc-text.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/fmt.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/ports.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/foreign.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/fmt-unicode.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/srfi-4.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/utf8-lolevel.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/sxml-transforms.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/chicken-doc.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/fmt.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/fmt-unicode.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/utf8-lolevel.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/sxml-transforms.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/matchable.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/regex.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/apropos.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/memoized-string.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/unicode-utils.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/type-checks.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/type-errors.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/symbol-utils.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/miscmacros.import.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/apropos.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/memoized-string.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/unicode-utils.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/type-checks.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/type-errors.so ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/symbol-utils.so ...
; loading library posix ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/srfi-18.import.so ...
; loading library srfi-18 ...
; loading C:\chicken/lib/chicken/8/tcp.import.so ...
; loading library tcp ...
#;14> (test 234235)
((result "((file-test-lock (\"args\" ((\"required\") (\"optional\" _ ...) (\"key\"))) (\"module\")) (test (\"args\" ((\"required\" x) (\"optional\") (\"key\"))) (\"module\")))") (output . ""))
#;18> 468470
#;19> (test2 9 9)

Error: unbound variable: test2

    Call history:

    <syntax>      (test2 9 9)
    <eval>    (test2 9 9)   <--
#;19>
```

Here is another example, I ran `toggle-debug-on-quit` and then hit `C-g` while it was hanging.  I can't make much of the backtrace though.  Here it is the buffer and backtrace:
Also, just for kicks I tried running Emacs as an administrator - that made no difference.
buffer:

```
(define (dog x) (+ x x))
(define (rog y x) (- x y))
(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))
```

backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  accept-process-output(#<process Chicken REPL> 3.0)
  geiser-con--send-string/wait((t (:filter . comint-output-filter) (:tq (("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(5235 cat)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 44) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(5235 cat)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer * Chicken REPL *>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 45) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 46) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(ta ta define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 47) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(ta ta define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 48) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 49) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(z tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 50) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(z tac define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 51) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ / define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 52) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ / define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 53) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ define)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 54) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))") (:continuation) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 55) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer * Chicken REPL *>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 56) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer * Chicken REPL *>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(8 tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 57) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(8 tac)))") (:continuation . geiser-autodoc--show-signatures) (:buffer . #<buffer * Chicken REPL *>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" ((:id . 58) (:string . "(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))") (:continuation . geiser-eval--set-sync-retort) (:buffer . #<buffer ck>) (:connection t (:filter . comint-output-filter) #1 (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter ... s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...))))) . geiser-con--process-completed-request)) #<process Chicken REPL> . #<buffer  tq-temp-Chicken REPL>) (:tq-filter lambda (p s) (geiser-con--tq-filter (quote ((("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(5235 cat)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(ta ta define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(z tac define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ / define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(/ define)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(geiser-autodoc '(8 tac)))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request) ("(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))\n" "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)" (... ... ... ... ...) . geiser-con--process-completed-request)) #<process Chicken REPL> . #<buffer  tq-temp-Chicken REPL>)) s)) (:eot . "\\(\n#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> \\)") (:prompt . "#[^;]*;[^:0-9]*:?[0-9]+> ") (:debug-prompt) (:is-debugging) (:count . 58) (:completed . #s(hash-table size 65 test eql weakness value rehash-size 1.5 rehash-threshold 0.8 data ( ...)))) "(geiser-eval '#f '(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y))))" geiser-eval--set-sync-retort nil nil)
  geiser-eval--send/wait((:eval (:scm "(begin (define (dog x) (+ x x))\n(define (rog y x) (- x y))\n(define (cat x y z) (* x y z))\n(define (tac y z) (/ x y)))")))
  geiser-debug--send-region(nil 1 110 geiser--go-to-repl t nil)
  geiser-eval-region(1 110 t nil nil)
  geiser-eval-buffer(t)
  geiser-eval-buffer-and-go()
  funcall-interactively(geiser-eval-buffer-and-go)
  call-interactively(geiser-eval-buffer-and-go nil nil)
  command-execute(geiser-eval-buffer-and-go)
```

Comment: Can you get anything evaluated at all? If you can reproduce your issue without any init file, I'd hand it in on their issue tracker.

Comment: Once it gets stuck, only what was already loaded gets evaluated.  No new expressions make it into the REPL or can be evaluated.  I already have an issue in the tracker and a couple of others have similar issues.  Kinda trying to get all the help I can get at this point.